# Difference between $(window).load() and $(document).ready() functions

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between `$(window).load(function() {})` and `$(document).ready(function() {})` in jQuery?

Comment: Note that in jQuey 3.x there is no `$(window).load()`. Use `$(window).on('load', function(){});` instead.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

- `document.ready` is a jQuery event, it runs when the DOM is ready, e.g. all **elements** are there to be found/used, but not necessarily all *content*.
- `window.onload` fires later (or at the same time in the worst/failing cases) when **images** and such are loaded, so if you're using image dimensions for example, you often want to use this instead.

Comment: shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})` is `$(function(){})` and another important difference from the window.load is that it will run on ALL future calls of the function, even after the initial DOMready.

Comment: are we to infer that `onload` is the same as `load`?

Comment: @dbliss Yes I believe onload is shorthand for `$(window).on('load')`. Both referencing the **load** event.

Comment: @MichaelButler - What do you mean with `it will run on ALL future calls of the function`?

Comment: @MichaelButler's comment is partially wrong. `$(document).ready(function(){})` is only executed once, when the DOM is ready. There is no such thing as "future calls".

Comment: @Doug S., sorry but you are wrong or misunderstood here.  See the jquery api documentation: "If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately."  my comment stands correct. We're talking about the ready function notan arbitrary specific callback handler.

Comment: @MichaelButler: You need to be more clear in your comment.

1) You're talking about the USER executing more `$(document).ready` code after the DOM is ready. That's such a small use case that it probably wasn't worth confusing everyone with mentioning it.

2) The ENVIRONMENT only calls `$(document).ready(f‌​unction(){})` once, when the DOM is ready. If the user, for some reason, executes more `$(document).ready` after the DOM is ready, then yes, it will be executed immediately.

Comment: @DougS I think you should delete your comments, you're just digging yourself into a hole now.

Comment: I beg to differ, Michael. Let's just leave it at this and not degrade into useless comments. At least the confused people now have their answer.

Answer (score 85):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 alert("document is ready");
});


$(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 alert("window is loaded");
});
```

Comment: Will 'load' execute again, if e.g. an Ajax request finished after the user started it by clicking a button?

Comment: @erik-stengel no!

Answer (score 48):

The `$(window).load()` is NOT available in jQuery 3.0

```
$( window ).load(function() {
        // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

To get around it, you can use it as an "Event Handler Attachment"

```
$( window ).on("load", function() {
        // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

Answer (score 20):

The difference are:

`$(document).ready(function() {` is jQuery event that is fired when DOM is loaded, so it’s fired when the document structure is ready.

`$(window).load()` event is fired after whole content is loaded.

Answer (score 10):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        alert( "document loaded" );
    });

    $( window ).load(function() {
        alert( "window loaded" );
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

window.load will be triggered after all the iframe content is loaded

Answer (score 8):

[**`$(document).ready`**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) happens when all the elements are present in the DOM, but not necessarily all content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("document is ready");
});
```

---

**`window.onload`** or [**`$(window).load()`**](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) happens after all the content resources (images, etc) have been loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert("window is loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From jquery prospective - it's just adding `load`/`onload` event to window and document.
Check this out:

[window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

Answer (score 2):

I think the `$(window).load` event is not supported by JQuery 3.x

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) the $(window).load event was removed in JQuery 3.0

Comment: This is correct.  In order to get around it, you can use it as an "Event Handler Attachment":
          $( window ).on("load", function() {
            // Handler for .load() called.
          });

Answer (score 1):

According to DOM Level 2 Events, the `load` event is supposed to fire on `document`, not on `window`. However, `load` is implemented on `window` in all browsers for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

**document.ready (jQuery)**
  document.ready will execute right after the HTML document is loaded property, and the DOM is ready.

DOM: The Document Object Model (DOM) is a cross-platform and language-independent convention for representing and interacting with objects in HTML, XHTML and XML documents.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
   alert("(document).ready was called - document is ready!");
});
```

**window.load (Built-in JavaScript)**
 The window.load however will wait for the page to be fully loaded, this 
   includes inner frames, images etc.
 * window.load is a built-in JavaScript method, it is known to have some quirks in old browsers (IE6, IE8, old FF and Opera versions) but will generally work in all of them.

window.load can be used in the body's onload event like this (but I would strongly suggest you avoid mixing code like this in the HTML, as it is a source for confusion later on):

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
   // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
   alert("(window).load was called - window is loaded!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> **$(window).load** is an event that fires when the DOM and all the content (everything) on the page is fully loaded like CSS, images and frames. One best example is if we want to get the actual image size or to get the details of anything we use it.
>
> **$(document).ready()** indicates that code in it need to be executed once the DOM got loaded and ready to be manipulated by script. It won't wait for the images to load for executing the jQuery script.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    //$(window).load was deprecated in 1.8, and removed in jquery 3.0
    // $(window).load(function() {
    //     alert("$(window).load fired");
    // });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("$(document).ready fired");
    });
</script>
```

> $(window).load fired after the $(document).ready().
>
> **$(window).load was deprecated in 1.8, and removed in jquery 3.0**