# jquery not loading in a script from another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I have the problem that I want to load a Javascript on a website from another website and use jQuery there. But it seems jQuery is never available.
I tried all the things in this post: [Test if jquery is loaded not using the document ready event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623982/test-if-jquery-is-loaded-not-using-the-document-ready-event).

Is it maybe a security cross site issue?

Here is the page:
[Japanese cities](http://www.japanese-cities.com/de/cities-de/hokkaido-tohoku-de/furano-de)

jQuery is loaded here in line 29

```
<script src="/cache/template/gzip.php?jquery.min-3eab6f02.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The script is loaded in line 343

```
    <script type="text/javaScript" src="http://www.factfish.com/api/js/japanese_cities.js"></script>
```

To narrow it down I just used an empty $ajax function

```
(function() {
if (jQuery) {
    $.ajax({});
}
})();
```

I always get the error

> TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Any ideas?

Thank you

Bernhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your page there's

```
<script src="/cache/template/gzip.php?jquery-noconflict-4baa84c1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which does this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

This means you

> Relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable

I.e. `$` is no longer associated with jQuery, and you must explicitly use `jQuery` instead.

See this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

This should work:

```
(function() {
    if (jQuery) {
        jQuery.ajax({});
    }
})();
```

Another way to do this:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {

    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
    $.ajax({});

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by `@dekkard`, you have effectively erased the `$` shortcut alias for jQuery.

As an alternative to the IIFE's shown by `@dekkard`, There is also a shortcut DOM ready that combines document.ready with a locally scoped `$`

e.g.

```
jQuery(function($){
    // Your DOM ready code - using a locally scoped $
});
```

*"Half the code, twice the flavour!"* :)