# Downloading ALL pdf from links in a specific div/table element of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, download

I have some link to PDFs given in a table inside a webpage, I want to download all of them via javascript, what do I do?

Edit:

Clearly speaking, I have a webpage here, I just look at it inside a browser, and I want to do some javascript that it automatically dwonloads all PDFs inside a specific table, that's all.

Comment: can you give the url of the website. so that it ll be easy write script

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your pdf links are enclosed in `<a>` tags having `href` attribute. You can do something like this.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
// Do this selection based on your table

for(var count=0; count<links.length; count++) {
    var url = links[count].getAttribute('href');
    if(url && url.endsWith('.pdf')) {
        links[count].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    }
}
```

For not opening pdf in browser itself you will have to disable this in browser. For chrome go to `chrome://plugins` and disable pdf viewer. Also if the number of pdfs to download is large, add some timeInterval between consecutive downloads. I hope this helps

Comment: Nice work. For adding `sleep` intervals see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep/39914235#39914235).

Answer (score 4):

Well finally I have got a way to do the task properly, see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckmichael8/0je5jnwb/) if you want to look further at it. This script automatically do everything as required by my previous problem, and it forces pdf download without disabling the viewer.

code:

```
(function(ElementTypeToDownload, DownloadFromWhere) {

  // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077242/force-download-a-pdf-link-using-javascript-ajax-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611497/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-html-page-in-javascript
  // Anonymous "self-invoking" function
  if (!(typeof jQuery === 'function')) {
    (function() {
      var startingTime = new Date().getTime();
      // Load the script
      var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
      script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

      // Poll for jQuery to come into existance
      var checkReady = function(callback) {
        if (window.jQuery) {
          callback(jQuery);
        } else {
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            checkReady(callback);
          }, 20);
        }
      };

      // Start polling...
      checkReady(function($) {
        $(function() {
          var endingTime = new Date().getTime();
          var tookTime = endingTime - startingTime;
        });
      });
    })();
  }
  // http://facebook.com/anders.tornblad
  // anders.tornblad@gmail.com

  // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077242/force-download-a-pdf-link-using-javascript-ajax-jquery
  function SaveToDisk(fileURL, fileName) {
    // for non-IE
    if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
      var save = document.createElement('a');
      save.href = fileURL;
      save.target = '_blank';
      save.download = fileName || fileURL.split("/").pop() || 'unknown';

      var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': false
      });
      save.dispatchEvent(evt);

      (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    }

    // for IE < 11
    else if (!!window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand) {
      var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
      _window.document.close();
      _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
      _window.close();
    }
  }

  // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623982/test-if-jquery-is-loaded-not-using-the-document-ready-event
  function preInit() {
    // wait until jquery is loeaded
    if (!(typeof jQuery === 'function')) {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        //console.log(count++);
        preInit();
      }, 10); // Try again every 10 ms..
      return;
    }

    $(ElementTypeToDownload || prompt("Enter the type of element you are going to download, e.g. 'a' for link, 'img' or 'image' for images (do not add quotes, deafult is 'a') ") || 'a', DownloadFromWhere || prompt("jQuery Selector for the place that you want to download content from, e.g. '#DivName', '.ClassName', 'TagName', body by deafult") || 'body').each(function() {
      var tag = (ElementTypeToDownload == 'img' || ElementTypeToDownload == 'image') ? 'src' : 'href';
      SaveToDisk($(this).attr(tag));
    });
  }

  preInit();
})();
```

Anyway thank you for you guys helping

Comment: If you already had worked it out, then why ask?

Comment: I asked because I found don't figure out how to achieve the result, but I found it when I have searched and combined multiple SO questions, so I made one on my own. Anyway big thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution with JavaScript

HTML:

```
<button id="download" name="download" type="button" onclick="download()">Some Text</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function download() {
    window.open("file_1.txt");
    window.open("file_2.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a button below your data to click it. on click all pdf files will start downloading.

> Please make sure that multiple download is restricted in your browser.
>   in chrome once you click on the download all button you have to make
>   sure that you click allow in the popup blocker which will be shown in
>   the right side of your address bar

```js
function clickall(){
  var pdfs = document.getElementsByClassName('mydata')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i=0; i<pdfs.length; i++) {
    pdfs[i].setAttribute("download", "download");
    pdfs[i].click();
  }
}

function excuteDomReadyCallBacks(){
  var mydata=document.getElementsByClassName('mydata')[0];
  var element = document.createElement('button');
                element.onclick = 'clickall()';
                element.value = 'download all';
                element.type = 'button';
  mydata[0].parent.insertAfter(element, mydata);
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
excuteDomReadyCallBacks();
    //.. do stuff ..
}, false);
```

```html
<table class="mydata">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
<td><b>City</b></td>
<td><b>State</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Greater Noida Cricket Stadium</td>
<td>Greater Noida</td>
<td>
  <a href="http://static.sportskeeda.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/hero-isl-2016-fixtures-1472219010.pdf">test2</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>    Buddh International Circuit</td>
<td>Greater Noida</td>
<td>
  <a href="/test2.pdf">test2</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>    Buddh International Circuit</td>
<td>Greater Noida</td>
<td>
  <a href="http://www.omri.org/sites/default/files/opl_pdf/CompleteCompany-NOP.pdf">test2</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```