# Why does window.onload work while document.onload doesn't?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why the following page doesn't trigger an alert when it loads? If I use `window.onload` instead of `document.onload` it works. Why is there this difference?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.onload = function() {
    alert('Test');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-loadfunction-and-document-readyfunction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest answer is that it just wasn't designed that way. The browser executes the function attached to `window.onload` at the "[end of the document loading process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)". It does not attempt to execute a function attached to `document.onload`.

You *could* assign a function to `document.onload` but the browser will not do anything special with it.

Some things to keep in mind (assuming you've just assigned a function to one or the other of `window.onload` or `document.onload`):

1. `window.onload === onload`
2. `window.onload !== document.onload`
3. `window !== document`

Comment: so is this the right way to think about it: the document object *does* have an onload method... but at no point in the process of loading the page is this method called... but, on the other hand, after loading the page the window's onload method is called... i'm new to javascript and trying to figure out how to conceptualize things

Comment: @zjmiller - Right, you *could* assign a function to `document.onload`, but the browser wouldn't do anything special with that function. The trick is that assigning to `window.onload` triggers special behavior. The `onload` property of `window` just happens to be the place that the browser looks for the function to call once the document loads.

Comment: What's the point of having the `onload` property on other elements than `window` then? :q

Answer (score 1):

The event handler is `onload` not `document.onload`. It hangs directly off the `window` object (which is the default object).

Comment: does the document object not have an onload method?