# Running JavaScript after page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I currently have a JavaScript file that I call in my view page in which I get my data information to display. At the same time I have this piece of JavaScript that shows a menu bar once the image has been clicked. This scripted is being ran before the page is loaded completely or something because it is not working. How can I make a piece of my JavaScript take action after all other scripts have completed running and page is loaded? this is what I tried but not working right

**JavaScript**

```
(function ($) {

.... lines to load view page with data

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('figure').on('click', function (event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('open');
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @mplungjan - `$` is passed in as a variable, but `$()` is never issued.

Comment: @mplungjan The outer expression is an IIFE, the inner is `$(document).ready`

Comment: @ian I saw that (didn't know the acronym) but ignored it since it looks more like some method to protect jquery than what is needed. We will see what OP actually needs

Comment: @mplungjan http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript

Comment: immediately-invoked function expression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `$(window).on("load")` instead of `$(document).ready` if you want to wait until all the elements have loaded in that case:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    $('figure').on('click', function (event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('open');
    });    
});
```

Comment: I have found that the load event for window is more appropriate than document.ready in certain cases as well.

Comment: I have never needed anything but $(function() {}); so far

Comment: @mplungjan - The situations I have needed to use the load version on window instead of document has been when images are still loading in parallax sites or when images are being rendered as the ready event fires. I have found that at times the dimensions can be slightly off when using ready in those situations.

Comment: This worked like a charm just waiting till i could mark it as answered.

Comment: I don't see how this is getting upvotes. `.load()` is deprecated in 1.8...

Comment: @jeffshaver it worked on my webapp when i made this change

Comment: @Amina I understand that. But why use deprecated code? It is never good to suggest using deprecated code

Comment: And my suggestion didn't ?

Comment: @JeffShaver - What replaced `load`? In these situations I usually just use `window.onload = function(){}` instead of jquery.

Comment: @jeffshaver what are the downfalls of using this method? before i posted my question here i wrote it how mplungjan suggested but it wasn't working that way.

Comment: @mplungjan You used document ready, which is what the OP already had. This is window load. It's not the same.

Comment: There's a difference between `.load()` being deprecated and the `"load"` event. Just use `.on("load", function () {});` instead then. There's a major difference between `$(window).on("load", function () {});` and `$(document).ready(function () {});`

Comment: @Amina the downfalls of using deprecated code is that if they actually `remove` it in jQuery 2.0 (or whatever the next version is) your code will break.

Comment: @Ian then suggest good code? `.load()` IS deprecated now. So if you want to suggest `.on('load'` I would upvote

Comment: @JeffShaver Updated. Sorry about that Amina I didn't mean to suggest using deprecated methods

Comment: Where does it say load is deprecated out of curiosity? It doesn't say it here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @JeffShaver I wasn't trying to defend them. I'm just saying, instead of downvoting for using `.load()`, it would probably be more useful to just suggest using `.on("load"`. And it's easier if this answer is just updated, as it already has been :)

Comment: @TravisJ look at the tags on the right side http://api.jquery.com/?s=.load

Comment: @TravisJ http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/

Comment: @TravisJ That `load()` is not deprecated, http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ is.

Comment: @JeffShaver the updated code also works great with me is that safely played than the previous code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-loadfunction-and-document-readyfunction

Comment: This has been a great and useful discussion. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Amina using `.on('load'` is fine. glad it solved the issue

Comment: @JeffShaver i have an infinite-scroll javascript question coming up you think you might be able to help? :D