# jquery width not getting set on server but on localhost it is setting correctly

Tags: jquery

Hi everyone I am using `outerWidth()` method to get `width` property of `input type="text"` field. which I am setting on the search box, It is setting correctly on localhost but not on server what is the issue can anybody help me. Here in code this is input box thanks

```
var search_id = $(this).attr('id');
var width = $(this).outerWidth();
<div id="total_div_'+search_id+'" tabindex="0" style="width:'+width+';max-height:230px
```

Comment: show code .have you coded something?

Comment: @user3245779 share yourr code ..

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I just added code can anybody suggest me what is wrong on server but not on localhost

Comment: is your code wrapped in document.ready, or window.load? I suggest using of second one...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-loadfunction-and-document-readyfunction, in this case. guess something related to loading speed on server... (little slower), so window.load should work...

Comment: @nevermind I am using this code in jquery plugin itself

Comment: @nevermind anyway width I am getting correctly

Comment: it has nothing to do with Server /localhost .Just check all JS are included or not .check for console error.

Comment: @user3245779 , u r getting it well then why did u ask question.

Comment: @PratikJoshi buddy just chill.On server I am getting width correctly as I checked on console log but it is not setting on div please review your comment thanks

Comment: give link of your web site URL ,so i can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do like below

```
$("#total_div_").css("width",""+ width +"px");
```

your code is wrong you are trying to add width varaible through style which can not ba work so try like above