# Jquery .hide not working on window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

This is driving me insane. At some point everything seemed to be working fine but suddenly everything stopped working and I have no idea why.

I have a set of divs with a class for which I want to hide everything but the first four divs.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">content 1</div>
    <div class="item">content 2</div>
    <div class="item">content 3</div>
    <div class="item">content 4</div>
    <div class="item">content 5</div>
</div>
```

And I have the following in the head of the doc

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".item:gt(3)").hide();
    }); 
</script>
```

Why doesn't this work?

I have to say the the ".item" divs load dynamically based on a variable that is set on the URL. Something like mydoamin.com/myitems/?zicode=10005

So the items displayed come from an external database and loaded in the page.

My assumption was that $(window).load waits for all those items to exist in the document. Am I wrong? and in that case, how can I make sure to execute a function only after everything is really loaded?

Comment: you need to wrap your code in a `ready` function => `$(function(){ //your code here });`

Comment: your code work correctly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4YRy/1/)

Comment: this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-loadfunction-and-document-readyfunction

Comment: When you say the items are loaded dynamically from a database, do you mean they are called in with ajax? Because that would change your needs completely.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `$(window).load(function() {` you need to use the function that waits for the DOM to be fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item:gt(3)").hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NKkX7/)

Comment: Still doesn't work because my items are loaded dynamically. if the items are already in the HTML then yes, this works. But since my items load at a different moment, how can I make sure that my .hide function is the last thing to be executed?

Comment: Then put your code to hide everything at the end of all executing code in the `$(document).ready()` function. This is one of the reasons why just spattering random function declarations that will run as they are hit is a bad idea. You "don't know" when they're run. Declare you functions as variables, and call them specifically before you try to hide anything.

Comment: Also, that revelation completely changes the way we'd all approach solving the issue. This is why sharing all of your code is important.

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).load()` is not the same as DOM ready. Use this instead:

```
$(function () {
    $(".item:gt(3)").hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/murrayju/FCvCs/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use something like this:

```
function itemHide() {
    $(".item:gt(3)").hide();
}
window.onload=itemHide;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The OP was already dong their work in the `window.onload` event.

Comment: @krillgar Could you please explain why downvote,because the way of using window.load is wrong. Have you tried the code or just downvote

Comment: The code that you posted is a pure JavaScript version of the code that the OP used with jQuery. Your line `window.onload=itemHide;` will run at the same time as `$(window).load(function() { itemHide(); });`. There is no difference between the two.