# Why Object expected error in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, debugging

I have simple web page having html, css and jquery. Purpose of this page is to demo horizontal collapse pane.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <title>Sample HTML</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #map {
            width: 10%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }

        #sidebar {
            width: 89%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        #toggle {
            height: 10%;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {//this is error line

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#toggle").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).data('name') == 'show') {
                        $("#sidebar").animate({
                            width: '10%'
                        }).hide()
                        $("#map").animate({
                            width: '89%'
                        });
                        $(this).data('name', 'hide')
                    } else {
                        $("#sidebar").animate({
                            width: '89%'
                        }).show()
                        $("#map").animate({
                            width: '10%'
                        });
                        $(this).data('name', 'show')
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>


    </head>
<body>

    <div id="map">
        <input type="button" data-name="show" value="Toggle" id="toggle"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used IE debugger and it hits at `$(window).load(function ()` saying *Object expected*. I do not understand why it is not working.

Also this page is taking long time to load.

Comment: are you loading the html file using the file protocol like `file://path-to-file`

Comment: @ArunPJohny No. I it is saved on my desktop. And I am opening it using IE and Chrome, both not working.

Comment: *"it is saved on my desktop"* So you *are* loading it from the file system and not from a web server? FYI, you only need either `(window).load(...)` or `$(document).ready(...)` but not both and certainly not nested.

Comment: is there any other error in the console

Comment: Based on the related questions, I'm 99% certain that you have to use `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use `$(window).load(function () {` as `$(document).ready` is there becuase `document.ready` fires when DOM is ready and `window.load` fires when images or any other resources loads. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-loadfunction-and-document-readyfunction) for more information.

Your error is coming because of jquery library path is incorrect, so check below path once again

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
```

I think it should start with `http://`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
```

And you can remove `window.load` after correcting the lib path and it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#toggle").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).data('name') == 'show') {
                        $("#sidebar").animate({
                            width: '10%'
                        }).hide()
                        $("#map").animate({
                            width: '89%'
                        });
                        $(this).data('name', 'hide')
                    } else {
                        $("#sidebar").animate({
                            width: '89%'
                        }).show()
                        $("#map").animate({
                            width: '10%'
                        });
                        $(this).data('name', 'show')
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please explain why the use of `$(window).load(function () {` in this situation would generate the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: To clarify why comment: While your suggestion is certainly correct, it doesn't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: I am not aware of the error mentioned in question but `document.ready` fires when DOM is ready and `window.load` fires when all resources,DOM are ready so there is no point in using `document.ready` inside `window.load`. And as OP using DOM elements inside the jquery script then there is no use of `window.load` as such. I am finding the exact reason behind the error.

Comment: This error comes when jquery library path is not correct.

Comment: [Yep, that's what I am thinking as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031086/why-object-expected-error-in-jquery/26031172?noredirect=1#comment40774647_26031086).

Comment: Oh yeah .. you already posted in comment, I found it on https://forum.jquery.com/topic/document-ready-throwing-object-expected-error :). I should have read comments first.