# Angularjs with Typescript Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'IndexViewModel' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Attempting a simple HTML TypeScript application and cannot get past this error noted in the subject when attempting to integrate Angularjs into the solution.  Basically, I have a simple index.html page as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.13" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Infrastructure.IndexViewModel">
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div id="content"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have created a simple class called IndexViewModel as follows:

module LogsModule {
    export class LogsViewModel {
        constructor($scope: ng.IScope, $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            console.info("logs view model constructed.");
        }
    }
}

I have also set the Visual Studio setting to ensure that all TypeScript files are combined into a single JavaScript file.

When I run the application, I get the error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Infrastructure.IndexViewModel' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=Infrastructure.IndexViewModel&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:63
    at assertArg (angular.js:1580)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1590)
    at angular.js:8431
    at angular.js:7599
    at forEach (angular.js:331)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7586)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7078)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7081)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:6957)
```

I have referenced [this](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs#readme) and [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) among others but still confused. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Error clearly says that angular controller is not registered with angular app.

By looking at your code, you didn't created angular module. Thats why you defined `ng-app=""` as a blank & you are trying to use global funtion. 
Above angular version 1.3 you need to use `angular.module()` to define your app, By default global functions are off.

Below is the code to define `angular.module`

**CODE**

```
var app= angular.module('app',[])

app.controller('Infrastructure.IndexViewModel',function($scope){
   //controller code here
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
```

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/G7HbIWgbdKGGmrOGPlM5?p=preview)

**Update**

**Brief how Angular JS works on page?**

1. Angular first gets content of html page.
2. It gather all the angular directives of page like `ng-app`, `ng-init`, `ng-model`,etc.
3. After that it compiles the page elements using [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service and directive gets call as per there mentioned priority.(All elements are get loaded on HTML page using `$compile` service)
4. At first `ng-app` directive will execute, It search for mentioned module in our case it is `app`.**(You've this error)**
5. In compilation phase directive [`compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) functions are called (if they exists).
6. At the time on rendering `ng-controller` directive load that angular controller.
7. As controller gets loaded with their DOM, respective directive link function gets call.(If there is any)

Instead of `window.load` you should use `angular.element(document).ready(function() {})` function as like we use `document.ready` [refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-loadfunction-and-document-readyfunction) or better inspite use `window.onload`. While creating app from `window.onload` you shouldn't mention `ng-app="app"` on you page, that will break the page, and will give the same error as your getting now (Refere point 4). Use `angular.bootstrap` to initialize app on page, after declaring all the module, this will initialize angular on page (lazy loading).

**Code**

```
//same can be do able with window.onload
  angular.element(document).ready(function() { 
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
      app.controller('Infrastructure.IndexViewModel', function() {
      });
    //bootstraping app on page
    angular.bootstrap(document,['app'])
  });
```

**HTML**(Don't mention `ng-app`)

```
<div ng-controller="Infrastructure.IndexViewModel">
  <input type="text" ng-model="test" />{{test}}
</div>
```

And there is no specific way to initialize angular on page, you can use seft executing function or normal adding global functions.

[**Updated Plukr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4cgn6OoiTe8FHxUkyEtg?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Where is the most appropriate place to put the initialization code?  You example uses the self executing function.  I have the same code in window.load event handler and get error that module 'app' is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a simple class called IndexViewModel as follows:
>   module LogsModule { export class LogsViewModel { constructor($scope: ng.IScope, $http: ng.IHttpService) { console.info("logs view model constructed."); } } }

The class is called `LogsViewModel` and its in `LogsModule`. So `ng-controller="Infrastructure.IndexViewModel">` should be `ng-controller="LogsModule.LogsViewModel">`