# how to set jquery callback before DOM is loaded?

Tags: jquery, dom

Can I run jquery code before DOM is loaded.

I want to run jquery on `window.onload` event.

I tried this :

```
window.onload=function($) {
  var url = $(location).attr("href");

        if (url.indexOf("1234") > 0)
            var nodeToHide = $('#1234');

            if(nodeToHide){
                var $parentToHide = $(nodeToHide).parent().closest("div[class='row']");
                if($parentToHide)
                    $parentToHide.hide();
            }
            };
```

But it gives an error.

**EDIT**
I moved to plain js. Code is now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function hideDiv1234() {
        var url = location.href;

        if (url.indexOf("1234") > 0){
            var headerToHide = document.getElementById('1234');

            var divParent = headerToHide.parentNode;
            if(divParent){
                divParent.parentNode.style.display="none";
            } else 
                divParent.style.display="none";
        }
    };      
    </script>
```

Unfortunately this function runs after page is shown on browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run code before `ready`, you can remove it from `ready` callback and put it open inside script. It will be executed when the element is reached at the time of parsing HTML.

If you want to run code after all the resources are loaded, use `load` event on `window`:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function ($) {
    // Your code here
}(jQuery));
```

For more clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4584475/2025923

Comment: Thanks, I want javascript code to run before page is shown because I need to remove one div so that user doesn't see it

Comment: @VovaProgrammer You can use CSS for this.

Comment: I need to check for certain url and if so hide div before page is loaded. See my edit

Comment: Then you need to add your script after the `div` is available in DOM.