# How to wait for full rendered image in Playwright

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright, image-rendering, image-load

I have a problem with one of my tests. In my project I use playwright 1.37.1 and typescript 5.1.6.
I want to compare images using snapshot method.
The thing is screenshot during of tests is not fully rendered and my assertions is always failed.
I try to use some waiter e.g. waitForSelector(), waitFotLoadState() but is not helping.
Only if I use code below it's working

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
```

Do you know better solutions? :)
Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a page is Full loaded and rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451112/check-if-a-page-is-full-loaded-and-rendered)

Comment: Still not :/ but I'm not sure if I used it properly in my method
async waitForLogo() {
    // Wrapping the window.onload event in a Promise for async usage
    await this.page.evaluate(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        window.onload = () => {
          resolve(true);
        };
      });
    });
  }

Comment: Please share a [mcve] so we can diagnose. You can [edit] code into your question.

Answer (score 2):

May be the image(s) loading lazily , try to scroll to wait till all images are loaded completely:

> In the below code, you will wait for all images in parallel to finish loading so
> it will wait only upto the load time of the image which takes maximum time to load.

```
// Trigger loading of all images
let locators=  page.locator('//img')
await locators.evaluateAll(e => e.scrollInfoView());
// Set up listeners concurrently
const promises = locators.map(locator => locator.evaluate(image => image.complete || new Promise(f => image.onload = f)));
// Wait for all once
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Reference:
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14388#issuecomment-1147769469