# Playwright: How can I scroll to element to load fire lazy loading?

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I have a page with hundreds of graphs that all display null values until you scroll them into view.

I want to assert the values for a specific graph that is halfway down the page, if I use `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()` and read the text I still get the null value, if I look in playwright UI I can see it's not scrolling down the page so I'm assuming because playwright can find the element it's not bothering to do to `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()`.

Is there a way I can force it to scroll to the locators so the null values will be replaced with actual ones?

Comment: It's hard to help without the site.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288613/

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I solved the similar problem. The solution come up with is the following:

1. Count number of rows in the view
2. Find the last TR element and call `scroll_into_view_if_needed`
3. Wait for the next TR element is visible
4. If the next elemnt appears repeat, otherwise you're done.

Here is some playwright psuedocode:

```py
table = page.locator(".table-classname")
rows_count = table.locator("tr").count()

while True:
    table.locator("tr").last.scroll_into_view_if_needed()
    table.locator(f"tr:nth-child({rows_count + 1})").last.wait_for()

    if rows_count == table.locator("tr").count():
        break

    rows_count = table.locator("tr").count()
```

I hope it will help