# get value from input field when the value data from json parse in javascript?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i have javascript with name something.js. in js file i have funtion like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
tampilInterval();       
$('#mydata').html();
function tampilInterval() {
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url:$("#baseurl").val(),
        dataType:"json",
        method:"post",
        success : function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            html += '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+data[0].key+'</td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="int0" name="int0" value="'+data[0].value+'"></td>'+
                '</tr><tr>'+
                '<td>'+data[1].key+'</td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="int1" name="int1" value="'+data[1].value+'"></td>'+
                '</tr>';
                $('#show_data').html(html);
        }
    });
};
```

in my case, i want to use value from id -> int0 and int1 to another function in same file.

i have code to get and check that values like this

```
var int0 = document.getElementsByName('int0').value;
var int1 = document.getElementById('int1');
```

but it said 'null'.
how to get that value ? or how to make variables `int0` and `int1` into global variables that already have value? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `document.getElementsByName()`, it will return a `NodeList`, which is kind of like an array. It doesn't have `value` directly. You would need to get the zero-th element on that array for the value:

```
var int0 = document.getElementsByName('int0')[0].value;
```

Note the `[0]`.

Comment: i got error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'. what i miss?

Comment: The element don't exists when you call `document.getElementsByName`. Note that the element MUST exists on the DOM when you call it.

Comment: It sounds like you might be either trying to get the element by the wrong identifier or trying to get it before it exists in the DOM. Try moving your `<script>` tag that pulls in your file to the very last line right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: I tried and the result is still the same, `null`
is this is possible to do?

Comment: Are you sure your function above has run BEFORE you try to grab the value from it? Since it is AJAX, it might be that your code to get the info is happening before the code that has created those elements. You can add `console.log()`s in both places to see if they are happening in the order you think they are.

Comment: And note, `document.getElementsByName('int0')[0].value` and `document.getElementById('int0').value` should both work, if called from the correct space.

Comment: Yes, it works if it not Ajax Function. i've tried to move my function in view data before tag closing `</body>`, but is still the same result.

Comment: like @Alexander said, the listener has not yet worked and did not assign it. so decide to put the data in type hidden without Ajax function and it works. But, thanks for your answer. i got something new to learn. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Oh sure. When the function `tampilInterval` is executed, it only sets the listener `success` that will be executed when the ajax-request completes.
If you are currently checking the value of the `int0` and `int1` DOM-nodes - the listener has not yet worked and did not assign it.

Comment: thank you, thats my problem. is there any other way to get that value?
i want to use `int0` and int `int1` in other function but in the same file 
thank you

Comment: You can't use the values ​​before the listener installs its. Therefore, the only way to solve your problem is to transfer your other function also inside this listener `success`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could store the variable globally and get it later.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var value1, value2;

tampilInterval();       
$('#mydata').html();
function tampilInterval() {
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'ajax',
        url:$("#baseurl").val(),
        dataType:"json",
        method:"post",
        success : function(data){
            value1 = data[0].value; value2 = data[1].value;
            var html = '';
            var i;
            html += '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+data[0].key+'</td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="int0" name="int0" value="'+data[0].value+'"></td>'+
                '</tr><tr>'+
                '<td>'+data[1].key+'</td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="int1" name="int1" value="'+data[1].value+'"></td>'+
                '</tr>';
                $('#show_data').html(html);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: i think this not work, because it's only work in tampilinterval function.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, so you need to get those elements using indexes.

```
var int0 = document.getElementsByName('int0')[0].value;
```

A better approach is to use the function `querySelector`, this way you don't need to worry about the indexes:

```
var int0 = document.querySelector('[name="int0"]').value;
```

## Resource

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

  > Returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors, or null if no matches are found.

Comment: i still get error like this
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`
and I've tried to removing `value`, but it said `null`. what i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$('#int0').val();
$('#int1').val();
```

You use jQuery to call ajax but the code below use javascript

If you want to add data after html loaded, use $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready()

[Difference between $(window).load() and $(document).ready() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready-functions)

Note : Use "Class" instead of "Id" in loop. Id is unique for the first tag

Comment: thanks @ryuk-lee, but if I use code, the result is the same. because function `tampiIInterval` is not run yet.