# Show Body loading before DOM is ready . i have already used preloader but still body show before DOM is ready

Tags: jquery

the loader shows after the screen deflection and then complete body shows. the jquery code takes time to load the complete body. I have tried all things but all in vain.

```js
$(window).load(function () {
        
                $(".preload").fadeOut(2000, function () {
                    $(".profile").fadeIn(1000);
                });
           
            });
```

```css
.preload {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preload">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KUJoe.gif">
        </div>
```

Comment: if you want your code to execute before DOM ready, the `<script>alert(1)</script>`  in `head` tag and see

Comment: Do it but still screen loads before the preloader how to get rid of it ..

Comment: can you share the `script` that you tired in `head` tag

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready-functions : `window.onload` fires later (or at the same time in the worst/failing cases) when images and such are loaded. the problem you will run into without it, however ; is that your preloader won't be guaranteed to be in the DOM either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#mySpinner').addClass('spinner');
$(window).on("load", function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#mySpinner').remove();
  },2000)
  
})
```

```css
#mySpinner{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
  background:#fff;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

@keyframes spinner {
from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.spinner:before {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: #07d;
  animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySpinner">

</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/450">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/450">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/450">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/450">
```

It is pure css preloader, u can add delay(setTimeout function) so that preloader is removed/hide when you want