# jQuery trigger select option after load

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, load

Pls can someone help me with code? I want to change option in select after page is loaded cuz form is generated with DOM.

I dont know why - with "onClick" is it working:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
 $( "#target" ).click(function() {
    $("#filter_1 option[value=11]").attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
 }); 
});
```

But i want to change select without click and this is not working:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $("#filter_1 option[value=11]").attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit - i found out that all "options" are not there yet, when i'm trying to change them. Working solution is:

```
$(function() {

  function changeOption() {
    $("#filter_1 option[value=11]").attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change'); 
  }

  setTimeout(function(){
    changeOption();
  }, 500);

});
```

Is there any better solution than Timeout?

Comment: Maybe you meant `$(window).on( "load"...`? Use `$(document).ready(function() { ...` to access the DOM after it's been loaded. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/   - if you wan to wait for all the images and iframes to load, you can use  `$(window).on( "load", function() { ... })` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready-functions/4584475

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.

First `$(window).load(func...` is deprecated. Use `$(function(){...` which is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function` instead

Next, there  is not change event on `<option>` you need to trigger it on the parent `<select>`

Finally you can simplify the `attr('selected')` on the option by just setting value of the parent `<select>`

```js
$(function() {

  // change event listener
  $('#filter_1').change(function() {
    console.log('Changed value to: ', this.value);
  })

  // set the value and trigger the change
  $('#filter_1').val(11).change()

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter_1">
  <option value=""> ---- </option>
  <option value="10"> 10 </option>
  <option value="11"> 11 </option>
  <option value="12"> 12 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your solution is were not working too. So i found out that all "options" are generated in on.load. And when i'm trying to change option the options are not there yet.

Comment: Still simpler to set the select value once the options do exist